# AVIF support on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, image-viewers, gthumb, av1

I have a few AVIF files. I can view them in Firefox, but I want to be able to open them in some image viewer/editor, and eventually convert them into another graphics format.

On Ubuntu Forums, I found an [old thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2468023) about AVIF format support in Ubuntu. It was mentioned in that thread that updating gThumb to newest version from [Ubuntu Handbook PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/apps) should provide AVIF support in gThumb.

I added that PPA and updated gThumb to version 3.12.8 (it updated several other packages as well, I provide the full apt log below), but gThumb is still unable to display AVIF images, contrary to what the thread author wrote in the forum post: "*Just updating with that PPA, not bothering to install anything new, fixed AVIF for existing apps such as Image Viewer and Nautilus.*" Not for me however.

What's interesting, the newly installed gThumb is able to **save** an image (opened initially in different format of course) as AVIF (and that AVIF file is properly opened eg. by Firefox), but cannot reopen that file again.

What can I do to make gThumb **open** AVIF files as well? I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Here's the full log from apt of what has been installed/updated from the PPA:

```
Install: libx265-192:amd64 (3.4-0sergeyd3.2~20.04.1, automatic), libjxl:amd64 (0.6.1~ppa1~focal, automatic), libaom3:amd64 (3.4.0-1~ppa1~focal2, automatic), libdav1d5:amd64 (0.8.1-0build1~20.04, automatic)
Upgrade: gthumb:amd64 (3:3.8.0-2.1ubuntu0.1, 3:3.12.4-0focal1), gthumb-data:amd64 (3:3.8.0-2.1ubuntu0.1, 3:3.12.4-0focal1), libheif1:amd64 (1.6.1-1build1, 1.11.0-0build5~focal), libde265-0:amd64 (1.0.4-1build1, 1.0.8-0build1~20.04)
```